# Denoise image algorithm using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a program that "denoises" a picture. I'm trying to grab only the non-border pixels and use the bordering pixels to set it's value, but it seems like my algorithm doesn't grab the intended pixels (I get a screwed up image as a result). If I understood correctly n=length, m=height (e.g. rows). I'm aware that I can use numpy to get a 3d-representation, but that isn't what I'm trying to do. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
def DenoiseImage(inputIm, factor, iters):

data = list(inputIm.getdata())
n, m = inputIm.size
data2 = data

for y in range (0, iters):

    #operate on pixels that aren't part of the top or bottom row
    for x in range (n, ((m-1)*n)-1):

        #makes sure x operated on isn't part of the left or right border
        if (x-1)%n != 0 and x%n != 0:
            #denoise pixel
            data[x] = data2[x] +factor*(data2[x-1]+data2[x+1]-4*data[x]+data2[x-n]+data2[x+n])

    temp = data2
    data2 = data
    data = temp

if iters%2==0:
    return data2
else:
    return data
```

This is the algorithm I'm trying to use (but it's written for a 2d-representation (and in C), obviously): http://pastebin.com/teEeUgFj

**EDIT:** Kinda a graphical representation of the thoughts behind the algorithm, bringing all my artistic talent to bear:

[image: derp]

Keep in mind m is the length downwards, so in the picture m would be = 4, not 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason causes this might be `data2 = data`. The process you change data will cause the same change in data2 which means they share the same block of memory. This will happen uniquely in python when you dealing some mutable classes such as list. You could use

`import copy
data2 = copy.copy(data)`

Or I suggest you to use scipy.signal.convolve2d to simplify your code and also will be much more efficient. Check [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely a problem. Now I get an output picture that isn't a 90% black box. I still have a problem, though: If I do 1 iteration, the output picture is more or less the same (this might be intended), but if I do many iterations (e.g. 10), then the output picture is just a "snowstorm". I did replace both data2 = data, and the temp use, with the copy thing. Ideas? It would seem the core denoise function doesn't work properly, but as far as I can see I've pretty much directly copypasted it from the algorithm I posted a link to.

Comment: Also, convoke2d seems to take 2d arrays as input, while the list I got is a 1 dimensional list.

Comment: Ooop, nevermind, I just had too high factor value (1), when I tried with 0.1 I got a working output picture. So I guess the only relevant question is the convoke one.

Comment: I might also add that I will make the code more efficient with numpy/weave. I was just making this version not using them to compare compile times.

Comment: @user2875994 Happy to hear that it went well. I suppose numpy would have `numpy.convolve` function which is easier to use for 1-d signal. The reason why I recommend `scipy.convolve2` is that I thought you were working on 2-d images. Anyway I do not recommend you transform it to a `list`, which is definitely less efficient than `numpy.ndarray` or `numpy.matrix`. I recommend you use them to make your code more efficient! In particular you are working on Image processing problem, efficiency matters a lot.

Comment: I am going to use numpy and weave. I'm just using a list version to compare efficiency. It's part of a university assignment.

Answer (score 1):

for python3 simply do

```
data2 = data.copy()
```